# Converting audio files to Linear16 format and streaming raw data to google speech api

Tags: node.js, swift, speech-recognition, google-speech-api, pcm

I'm working on a small app to stream audio data to the google speech api. I managed to cobble together the following functions from various stack overflow posts to convert local audio files to linear16 format. I'm then sending the data over udp to my server where its streamed to the google speech API. The issue is that the audio is not recognized as it should be. I notice that if I change Uint16Array to Uint8Array on the node server I start to get some results from the server however this is converting the 16 bit data to 8 bit data, I don't believe this conversion should be necessary.

Code to send to google speech. The raw data is written to the stream:

```
export const streamingRecognize = ({
  config,
  cb,
}: {
  config: SpeechToText.GsConfig
  cb?: (data: SpeechRecognitionResult) => void
}): Writable => {
  const request = {
    config,
    singleUtterance: false,
    interimResults: true, //Get interim results from stream
    enableWordTimeOffsets: true
  }
  const client = new speech.SpeechClient({ credentials: keyAndEmail })
  return client
    .streamingRecognize(request)
    .on('error', (err) => console.log(err))
    .on('data', (data) => {
      cb && cb(data)
    })
}
export const openStream = (audioConfig, callback) =>
  streamingRecognize({
    config: {
      languageCode: audioConfig.languageCode,
      sampleRateHertz: parseInt(audioConfig.sampleRateHertz),
      encoding: audioConfig.encoding as any
    },
    cb: (data: any) => {
      callback(data)
    },
  })b(data)
  })
const stream = openStream({
  sampleRateHertz: 16000,
  languageCode: 'en-US',
  encoding: 'LINEAR16' as any,
}, (data) => {
  console.log(data)
})
// here data is the linear16 audio data received from the ios client
const audioData = new Uint16Array(data)
const audioDataBuffer = Buffer.from(audioData)
stream.write(audioDataBuffer)
```

code to read the file and send the raw audio data to server.

```
import AVFoundation

extension Recorder {
  func openFile(
    _ args: NSDictionary,
    resolver resolve: @escaping RCTPromiseResolveBlock,
    rejecter reject: @escaping RCTPromiseRejectBlock
  ) {
    self.delegate?.stopSignaling()
    let withSignaling: Bool = (args["withSignaling"] != nil)
    let fullPath = args["url"]! as! String
    let userId = args["userId"] as! String
    let parts = fullPath.components(separatedBy: "/")
    let filename = parts[parts.count - 1]
    let sendData: (_ data: UnsafeMutableRawPointer, _ byteSize: Int) -> Void = {
      [weak self] data, byteSize in
      guard let weakself = self else {
        return
      }
      let imageData: Data = Data(bytes: data, count: byteSize)
      weakself.delegate?.sendEvent(
        withName: "fileTranscription",
        body: [
          "key": userId + "|" + filename,
          "data": imageData.withUnsafeBytes {
            Array($0.bindMemory(to: Int16.self)).map(Int16.init(bigEndian:))
          }
        ]
      )
      if (withSignaling) {
        weakself.delegate?.onAudioData(imageData)
      }
    }
    let attemptToConnect: () -> Void = {
      [weak self] in
      guard let weakself = self else {
        return
      }
      do {
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: fullPath)
        let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
        let format = AVAudioFormat(commonFormat: .pcmFormatInt16, sampleRate: 16000, channels: 1, interleaved: false)!
        _ = data.convertedTo(format, sendData)
        resolve(userId + "|" + filename)
        if (withSignaling) {
          weakself.delegate?.stopSignaling()
        }
      } catch {
        print("an error occured", error)
      }
    }
    if (withSignaling) {
      do {
        try self.delegate?.startSignaling([
          "filename": filename,
          "userId": args["userId"]!,
          "languageCode": args["languageCode"]!,
          "sampleRateHertz": args["sampleRateHertz"]!,
          "encoding": args["encoding"]!
        ], attemptToConnect)
      } catch {}
    } else {
      attemptToConnect()
    }
  }
}

func data_AudioFile_ReadProc(_ inClientData: UnsafeMutableRawPointer, _ inPosition: Int64, _ requestCount: UInt32, _ buffer: UnsafeMutableRawPointer, _ actualCount: UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt32>) -> OSStatus {
    let data = inClientData.assumingMemoryBound(to: Data.self).pointee
    let bufferPointer = UnsafeMutableRawBufferPointer(start: buffer, count: Int(requestCount))
    let copied = data.copyBytes(to: bufferPointer, from: Int(inPosition) ..< Int(inPosition) + Int(requestCount))
    actualCount.pointee = UInt32(copied)
    return noErr
}

func data_AudioFile_GetSizeProc(_ inClientData: UnsafeMutableRawPointer) -> Int64 {
    let data = inClientData.assumingMemoryBound(to: Data.self).pointee
    return Int64(data.count)
}

extension Data {
  func convertedTo(_ format: AVAudioFormat, _ cb: ((_ data: UnsafeMutableRawPointer, _ byteSize: Int) -> Void)? = nil) -> AVAudioPCMBuffer? {
    var data = self

    var af: AudioFileID? = nil
    var status = AudioFileOpenWithCallbacks(&data, data_AudioFile_ReadProc, nil, data_AudioFile_GetSizeProc(_:), nil, 0, &af)
    guard status == noErr, af != nil else {
      return nil
    }

    defer {
      AudioFileClose(af!)
    }

    var eaf: ExtAudioFileRef? = nil
    status = ExtAudioFileWrapAudioFileID(af!, false, &eaf)
    guard status == noErr, eaf != nil else {
      return nil
    }

    defer {
      ExtAudioFileDispose(eaf!)
    }

    var clientFormat = format.streamDescription.pointee
    status = ExtAudioFileSetProperty(eaf!, kExtAudioFileProperty_ClientDataFormat, UInt32(MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: clientFormat)), &clientFormat)
    guard status == noErr else {
        return nil
    }

    if let channelLayout = format.channelLayout {
      var clientChannelLayout = channelLayout.layout.pointee
      status = ExtAudioFileSetProperty(eaf!, kExtAudioFileProperty_ClientChannelLayout, UInt32(MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: clientChannelLayout)), &clientChannelLayout)
      guard status == noErr else {
        return nil
      }
    }

    var frameLength: Int64 = 0
    var propertySize: UInt32 = UInt32(MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: frameLength))
    status = ExtAudioFileGetProperty(eaf!, kExtAudioFileProperty_FileLengthFrames, &propertySize, &frameLength)
    guard status == noErr else {
      return nil
    }

    guard let pcmBuffer = AVAudioPCMBuffer(pcmFormat: format, frameCapacity: AVAudioFrameCount(frameLength)) else {
      return nil
    }
    // 16000 samples per second
    // 0.1s * 16000 = 1600
    // 2 bytes per frame = 3200 buffer size
    let bufferSizeFrames = 1600
    let bufferSizeBytes = Int(format.streamDescription.pointee.mBytesPerFrame) * bufferSizeFrames
    let numBuffers = format.isInterleaved ? 1 : Int(format.channelCount)
    let numInterleavedChannels = format.isInterleaved ? Int(format.channelCount) : 1
    let audioBufferList = AudioBufferList.allocate(maximumBuffers: numBuffers)
    for i in 0 ..< numBuffers {
      audioBufferList[i] = AudioBuffer(mNumberChannels: UInt32(numInterleavedChannels), mDataByteSize: UInt32(bufferSizeBytes), mData: malloc(bufferSizeBytes))
    }

    defer {
      for buffer in audioBufferList {
        free(buffer.mData)
      }
      free(audioBufferList.unsafeMutablePointer)
    }

    while true {
      var frameCount: UInt32 = UInt32(bufferSizeFrames)
      status = ExtAudioFileRead(eaf!, &frameCount, audioBufferList.unsafeMutablePointer)
      guard status == noErr else {
        return nil
      }

      if frameCount == 0 {
        break
      }

      let src = audioBufferList
      let dst = UnsafeMutableAudioBufferListPointer(pcmBuffer.mutableAudioBufferList)

      if src.count != dst.count {
        return nil
      }
    
      for i in 0 ..< src.count {
        let srcBuf = src[i]
        let dstBuf = dst[i]
        if cb != nil {
          cb!(srcBuf.mData!, Int(srcBuf.mDataByteSize))
        }
        memcpy(dstBuf.mData?.advanced(by: Int(dstBuf.mDataByteSize)), srcBuf.mData, Int(srcBuf.mDataByteSize))
      }

      pcmBuffer.frameLength += frameCount
    }

    return pcmBuffer
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1/using this sample

https://github.com/googlesamples/assistant-sdk-python/blob/master/google-assistant-sdk/googlesamples/assistant/grpc/audiofileinput.py

to create a def

```
def speech2text(audio_stream):

....
```

2/Using pyaudio to create stream that are input for 1 like this:

```
def main():
    start_time=get_current_time()        
    final_result=''
    while get_current_time() - start_time < STREAMING_LIMIT:    
        pa = None
        audio_stream = None    
        # try:
            # porcupine = pvporcupine.create(keywords=keywords,sensitivities=sensitivities)
        pa = pyaudio.PyAudio()
        audio_stream = pa.open(
                        rate=DEFAULT_AUDIO_SAMPLE_RATE,
                        channels=1,
                        format=pyaudio.paInt16,
                        input=True,
                        output_device_index=None,
                    frames_per_buffer=512)                    
        final_result=speech2text(audio_stream)
        if len(final_result) >0:
            print(colored('[HUMAN]: '+final_result,'yellow'))            
        pa.terminate()
        audio_stream.close()   
        break
```